# pid of a process created by python subprocess.Popen(shell=True) is not the pid of the spawned shell

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

i have a python script for test:

```
test.py:
#coding=utf-8
import os
import time

print os.getpid()
```

call it by subprocess.Popen:

```
p = sp.Popen("python test.py", shell=True)
print p.pid
```

different outputs of these two print statement are expected as p.pid should be the pid of the shell process spawned, but the real output is:

```
In [18]: p = sp.Popen("python test.py", shell=True)

In [19]: 19108

In [19]: p.pid
Out[19]: 19108
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are on UNIX/Linux.  If I may restate your question, I think you're asking, given

```
p = subprocess.Popen("python test.py", shell=True)
```

why is `p.pid` the same as that of the `test.py` process rather than that of the intervening *shell*, which shell you explicitly requested?  That is, you expect the process genealogy to look like this:

```
python (calling subprocess.Popen)   # pid 123
  \_ /bin/sh -c 'python test.py'    # pid 124
      \_ python test.py             # pid 125  # note: pids need not be sequential, that's just for demonstration
```

The answer is, **your shell is making an optimization.**  The shell recognizes that it has been given a simple command and simply `execve`s that command, replacing itself — but not its PID, of course — with the new process.  So, the genealogy looks like this:

```
python (calling Popen)                          # pid 201
  \_ /bin/sh -c ... --execve--> python test.py  # pid 202
```

On Linux you can [`strace -fe trace=process ...`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to confirm this.  You'll see the top-level python process fork (er, [`clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone)) and then the child will exec `/bin/sh` and then again `python`.

Comment: On Windows, the shell (cmd) is not that smart, the tree is maintained, so with p.pid you get the pid of the shell and the script shows the pid of the python process. You get: `python (pidX) -> cmd (pidY) -> python (pidZ)`

Comment: @JoaquinSargiotto, right.  My inference is that the OP is on a *NIX system.

Comment: you're right, by strace i can see `clone` is called just once